# How to share Flutter_App_link to social media like facebook, twitter, instagram?

Tags: flutter, dart, share, media, social-media

I just want to share my app link to social media like facebook, twitter, Instagram but currently just wanna share simple text on social media.

here, what I have tried:

I used `social_share_plugin` package but getting an Exception on compile time.

code for facebook

```
IconButton(
  icon:Image.asset("assets/icons/facebook_logo1.png",fit:BoxFit.contain,color: Colors.white,),
  onPressed: ()async{
    String faceString="Sharing My App";       
    await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebook('caption', faceString);
 },
),
```

for instagram

```
IconButton(
  icon:Image.asset("assets/icons/instagram_logo1.png",fit:BoxFit.contain,color: Colors.white,),
  onPressed: ()async{
    String instaString="Sharing My App";       
    await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedInstagram('caption', instaString);
 },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_social_content_share

```
/// SHARE ON FACEBOOK CALL
  shareOnFacebook() async {
    String result = await FlutterSocialContentShare.share(
        type: ShareType.facebookWithoutImage,
        url: "https://www.apple.com",
        quote: "captions");
    print(result);
  }

  /// SHARE ON INSTAGRAM CALL
  shareOnInstagram() async {
    String result = await FlutterSocialContentShare.share(
        type: ShareType.instagramWithImageUrl,
        imageUrl:
            "https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/healthy-eating-ingredients-732x549-thumbnail-732x549.jpg");
    print(result);
  }

  /// SHARE ON WHATSAPP CALL
  shareWatsapp() async {
    String result = await FlutterSocialContentShare.shareOnWhatsapp(
        number: "xxxxxx", text: "Text appears here");
    print(result);
  }

  /// SHARE ON EMAIL CALL
  shareEmail() async {
    String result = await FlutterSocialContentShare.shareOnEmail(
        recipients: ["xxxx.xxx@gmail.com"],
        subject: "Subject appears here",
        body: "Body appears here",
        isHTML: true); //default isHTML: False
    print(result);
  }

  /// SHARE ON SMS CALL
  shareSMS() async {
    String result = await FlutterSocialContentShare.shareOnSMS(
        recipients: ["xxxxxx"], text: "Text appears here");
    print(result);
  }

  ///Build Context
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Share to facebook button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                shareOnFacebook();
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Share to instagram button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                shareOnInstagram();
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Share to whatsapp button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                shareWatsapp();
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Share to email button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                shareEmail();
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Share to sms button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                shareSMS();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

and then here is how you share your data

```
    import 'package:share/share.dart';
IconButton(
  icon:Image.asset("assets/icons/facebook_logo1.png",fit:BoxFit.contain,color: Colors.white,),

        onPressed: (){
       Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
        }
`),
```

Comment: I used it but it's not as I required.

Comment: share a link to social_share_plugin

Comment: Thank you but I already used it. and this plug only allows me to share files not String or link. and for twitter, it does not work.

Comment: I used  `flutter_share_me` plugin but for Instagram, haven't defined